# How to print posts with associated tags?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my database schema:

```
Post:
id
title
body
date

Tag:
id
title

Post_Tag:
id
id_post
id_tag

Comment:
id
id_post
body
date
```

There is a many to many relationship between post and tag.

I need to print in homepage this for the latest 10 posts:

```
<a href="post.php?id=ID_POST">POST_TITLE</a>

POST_BODY

<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_1"> TAG_TITLE_1 </a>
<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_2"> TAG_TITLE_2 </a>
<a href="tag.php?id=ID_TAG_3"> TAG_TITLE_3 </a>

COMMENTS_NUMBER
```

What is the best query to do that ?

I have the query below but it doesn't work well because in the "tags" column of the results, I get something like this: "[BLOB - 38B]".

```
SELECT
    Post.id AS post_id,
    Post.title AS post_title,
    Post.body AS post_body,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Tag.id, "|", Tag.title) SEPARATOR '#') AS tags,
    COUNT(Comment.id) AS comment_count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Post.id = Comment.id_post
LEFT JOIN Post_Tag ON Post.id = Post_Tag.id_post
LEFT JOIN Tag ON Tag.id = Post_Tag.id_tag
GROUP BY Post.id
ORDER BY Post.date ASC
```

Is this the correct way to do this or I need to do 1 query to get all posts and 1 query for each posts to get all associated tags ?

Comment: This is a correct way, you need to add indexes and all will work much faster than with separate queries

Comment: ok but  in the "tags" column of the results, I get something like this: "[BLOB - 38B]" so it doesn't work.

Comment: For that you need to convert that line to UTF8, `CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Tag.id, "|", Tag.title) SEPARATOR '#') AS tags USING utf8)`